# Creating one invoice for two different opportunites

Tags: opportunity

Is there a way to create one invoice for two different opportunities. The issue is having one opportunity that is a renewal and the other being new business. At the moment we have them both under one opportunity because they are both the same company just different departments. But I would like to create them into two different opportunities but only want to send them one invoice? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not natively.  You could build a way for users to select multiple opportunities, and then use a Visualforce page to combine their contents into a single document. The Visualforce page can be **[rendered as a pdf](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_renderas_pdf.htm)**, and that could serve as your invoice.

There are 3rd party tools, like Drawloop and Conga, that could handle it as well.  That's probably the way I'd go if you have the budget

Comment: Are you familiar enough with Visualforce to be able to provide the code that would be able to solve for this. Ideally it would be great if the sales team could just select the certain opps that they want their invoices merged and to just click a button that does that (I dont know if that can be done) If not any documentation would be great as my visualforce skills are not great!

Comment: Ooh.  I am, but that would take me a while!  I'd be glad to point you in the right direction though.  Start by taking a look at the standardSetController documentation.  That will let you use the native Opportunity listview as the source for selecting opportunities that should be included in the pdf.  From there, it's just a matter of designing the pdf layout in visualforce/HTML, looping through the relevant information in the selected opportunities to include it in the layout.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008ni4IAA

Comment: ...that said, since you're still new to Visualforce, I'd recommend going with a 3rd party application.  Here's a (very old) video showing how Drawloop handles something similar to your use case:   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIYpzxbcu7o

Comment: If going the 3rd party application route is what I go with, do you recommend Drawloop or Conga?

Comment: It's a toss-up really.  I've used both, and they each have their ups-and-downs. Either would work well for what you're trying to do though.  Check out pricing and see who gives you the better deal!